# set marker google maps javascript api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, marker

I am trying to create with the google maps javascript api the following: After page loading a marker should become set at the users location, what now works. After that should where the user click on the map a marker become added and the previous one deleted. One marker should be only on the map. Now the previous marker wont become deleted and other become added what I dont want. What can I do to have always one marker on the map?

```
var markers = [];
    function initMap() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
        zoom: 7
      });
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});

      // Try HTML5 geolocation.
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
          var pos = {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude
          };

          map.setCenter(pos);


      // This event listener will call addMarker() when the map is clicked.
      map.addListener('click', function(event) {
        deleteMarkers();
addMarkers(event.latLng);


      });
      addMarkers(pos);
      // Adds a marker to the map and push to the array.
      function addMarkers(location) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map
      });
      markers.push(marker);
    }
  // Sets the map on all markers in the array.
  function setMapOnAll(map) {
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    markers[i].setMap(map);
  }
}
// Removes the markers from the map, but keeps them in the array.
function clearMarkers() {
  setMapOnAll(null);
}


    // Deletes all markers in the array by removing references to them.
    function deleteMarkers() {
        clearMarkers();
      marker = [];
    }


        }, function() {
          handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        });

      } else {
        // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
        handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
      }

    }
```

Comment: I get a javascript error with the posted code `Uncaught ReferenceError: markers is not defined`

Comment: When I fix that and push the original marker onto the array it works for me.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didnt notice your comments. Would you be so nice and post the working code as an answer?

Comment: With my actually code I get ´Uncaught TypeError: marker.push is not a function´

Comment: I get it by myself but thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove) I believe you are close :)

you are just setting your markers array to be nothing , but not actaully clearing the marker

Comment: Thanks but I made from this example my previous code :D

Comment: well look at the example again and follow the onclick handler for the Delete Marker button. you can see that it calls ClearMarkers() which in turn calls SetMapOnAll(map) where it loops through the markers and sets the map again for each marker using SetMap().

Comment: Ok, Ive updated my code but now the onclick event wont work :D

Comment: create a JSFiddle so it can be looked into more or post your revised code otherwise we cannot see what is happening we just know it is 'not working' :)

Comment: I cant create a fiddle because of my api key :/

Comment: take a look at what you are doing on your onClick event. You first say to delete the marker , then you call addmarker() which inside that is where you first create the 'marker'.. so when you first click on the map, your expected behaviour is that it would clear any existing markers, then add one buttttttttt when it goes to do the clear, its like hey what is this marker you speak of you want me to clear then throws the error and does not do what you want

Comment: Thanks for your help, I edit my code but actually dont know whats wrong.

Comment: The issue right now is that deleteMarker() is trying to delete a marker that hasn't even been created yet.

take a look at @geocodezip 's comment it states that it was 'fixed' and then added to the marker array. I believe it was 'fixed' by creating the marker outside of the addMarker() function so when the deleteMarker() function is called it wont throw an error saying it is not defined :)