# get current position of marker in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to get the current position that mean longitude and latitude of the marker. First a marker becomes created at the users location and when the user click on the map the previous one becomes deleted and a new one becomes created at the users clickpoint. I tried it by my own with `var lat1 = markers.position.lat(); var lng1 = markers.position.lng();` but that havent work and I get with this the error message `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined`. How can I get the current position of the marker and save it in a variable?

```js
var markers = [];
// This event listener will call addMarker() when the map is clicked.
map.addListener('click', function(event) {
  addMarkers(event.latLng);
});
//draw a marker at the position of the user
addMarkers(pos);
// Adds a marker to the map and push to the array.
function addMarkers(location) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map
  });
  markers.push(marker);
}
// Sets the map on all markers in the array.
function setMapOnAll(map) {
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    markers[i].setMap(map);
  }
}
// Removes the markers from the map, but keeps them in the array.
function clearMarkers() {
  setMapOnAll(null);
}
// Deletes all markers in the array by removing references to them.
function deleteMarkers() {
  clearMarkers();
  marker = [];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

markers is an array.

try

```
markers[0].position.lng();
```

to get the first marker

or

```
markers[markers.length-1].position;
```

to get the last marker

Comment: Yes thanks I forget it thats an array. I tried it with both and I made your second offer  to ´markers[markers.length-1].position.lng();´ after edit that, I add ´console.log(lat1);´ but cant see something. Only `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'position' of undefined`

Comment: Sorry but... why put your markers in an array if as you say *the previous one becomes deleted and a new one becomes created*? Why don't you just update the marker position?

Comment: @Bodoppels why dont you do a console.log(markers) then expand the elements and see what is going on?

Comment: @MrUpsidown Yes that sounds like a smarter solution :D

Comment: Oh sorry I had my code outside the function your second offer works well :)

Answer (score 0):

The variable `pos` is not defined initially.

> First a marker becomes created at the users location

What do you mean by the user's location? If it is the center of the map, then you can do this:

```
var pos = map.getCenter();
addMarkers(pos);
```

Comment: I havent posted my whole code only a pice of it that it isnt too much and I define ´pos´ before that and that works all well. :)

Comment: @RedHotScalability: because I tested the remaining code, which works fine. And I couldn't think of any other way property 'lat' of an undefined variable could be accessed. And this whole code is copied from the google-maps-api's samples: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove

Comment: Sorry but I agree with @jatinderjit. We can't guess what `pos` is unless it's somewhere in your code or if you explain what it is and how you set it's value.

Comment: Yes sorry but I wrote that this function worked and I thought that its self explaining. :)

Comment: @Bodoppels could you please provide the details if it is defined elsewhere?

Comment: at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34597388/set-marker-google-maps-javascript-api is my whole code.

Comment: Please don't post the same questions multiple times... This won't get you quicker help. Only downvotes maybe...